# Tesseract fails to parse text from image

Tags: opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm completely new to opencv and tesseract.
I spent all day trying to make code that would parse game duration from images like that: [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2zRx.jpg) (game duration is in the top left corner)

I came to code that manages to recognize the duration sometimes (about 40% of all cases). Here it is:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import os
import cv2
import pytesseract
import re
import json

def non_digit_split(s):
    return filter(None, re.split(r'(\d+)', s))

def time_to_sec(min, sec):
    return (int(min) * 60 + int(sec)).__str__()

def process_img(image_url):
    img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./images/' + image_url), None, fx=5, fy=5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    str = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

    if "WIN " in str:
        time = list(non_digit_split(str.split("WIN ",1)[1][0:6].strip()))
        str = time_to_sec(time[0], time[2])
    else:
        str = 'Not recognized'
    return str

res = {}
img_list = os.listdir('./images')
print(img_list)

for i in img_list:
    res[i] = process_img(i)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(res))
```

Don't even ask how I came to resizing image, but it helped a little.
I also tried to crop image first like that:
[cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvK9X.jpg)
but tesseract couldn't find any text here.

I'm sure that the issue I'm trying to solve is pretty easy. Can you please point me the right direction? How should I preprocess it so tesseract will parse it right?

Comment: You need to crop image and make it black & white, where black is text (and only text!) and white is everything else.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Thank you. I'll try to go in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DmitriiZ comment I managed to produce working piece of code.
I made a preprocessor that outputs something like that:
[Preprocessed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVi8U.jpg)
Tesseract handles it just fine.

Here is the full code:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import os
import pytesseract
import json

def is_dark(image):
    pixels = image.getdata()
    black_thresh = 100
    nblack = 0
    for pixel in pixels:
        if (sum(pixel) / 3) < black_thresh:
            nblack += 1
    n = len(pixels)

    if (nblack / float(n)) > 0.5:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def preprocess(img):
    basewidth = 500
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))

    #Enlarging image
    img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    #Converting image to black and white
    img = img.convert("1", dither=Image.NONE)
    return img

def process_img(image_url):
    img = Image.open('./images/' + image_url)

    #Area we need to crop can be found in one of two different areas,
    #depending on which team won. You can replace that block and is_dark()
    #function by just img.crop().
    top_area = (287, 15, 332, 32)
    crop = img.crop(top_area)
    if is_dark(crop):
        bot_area = (287, 373, 332, 390)
        crop = img.crop(bot_area)

    img = preprocess(crop)

    str = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

    return str

res = {}
img_list = os.listdir('./images')
print(img_list)

for i in img_list:
    res[i] = process_img(i)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(res))
```